# sci-kit learn: Data size error with pandas and SciKit

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am discovering machine learning with sci-kit. I use pandasto import my data from two CSVs.

My X vector has 2 columns and 100 000 rows. My Y vector has 1 column and 100 000 rows.

Here is my code :

```
Returns 2 arrays X et Y
def extract_data(data_set_1, data_set_2):

data_set_1 = pd.read_csv(data_set_1, header = None);
data_set_2 = pd.read_csv(data_set_2, header = None);

X = np.asarray(data_set_1)
Y = np.asarray(data_set_2)
return X,Y

X,Y = extract_data('../data_sets/data_set_4_X.csv', '../data_sets/data_set_4_Y.csv')

y = []
for i in range(len(Y)):
    y.append(Y[i][0])

Y = np.array(y)

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf')
clf.kernel

clf.fit(X, Y)
r = clf.predict(X[0])
```

So my X vector is like :

```
array([[ 2.0968 ,  1.0738 ],
       [ 2.5673 , -0.89561],
       [ 0.1616 ,  0.72648],
       ..., 
       [-2.4634 ,  1.6515 ],
       [ 1.8333 , -2.6854 ],
       [ 0.63995, -1.6925 ]])
```

And my Y vector :

```
array([ 1,  1, -1, ...,  1,  1,  1], dtype=int64)
```

When I run the code, I have the following error :

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 2.0968  1.0738].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

[ 2.0968  1.0738] is the first row of my X vector, I can't find why I have this error.

Thanks !

Comment: `r = clf.predict(X[0])` must be either `r = clf.predict(X)` or `r = clf.predict([X[0]])`. `clf.predict` takes a 2D array.